# How to make side-scrollable screens in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to practice different functionalities in Android using Android Studio.

Right now I wish to make it so I can swipe left/right between various components.

A good example of this is the app called Simple Workout Log. The top bar is scrollable (in a more localized way) whereas the bottom of the screen scrolls over entirely with each swipe.

I did notice something called HorizontalScrollView in Android Studio but couldn't figure out how to mimic the functionality.

How is something like this made?

Comment: Are you talking about a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)?

Comment: Possibly... I don't see the option for it anywhere in Android Studio though

Comment: It's in the v4 support library.

Comment: Does that mean it doesn't show up in the UI anywhere?

Comment: Not unless you've downloaded/added the library, I would imagine. I'm not familiar with Android Studio, but have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35968394/4409409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `tabbed activity` and it will automatically implement `view pager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` for you.
After that you can look up for tutorials on `creating tabs` using `frgments` such as [this one](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)