# fragment from viewPager hidding behind on tab of action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

Actually i am trying to build a listView/recyclerView . On scrolling of list the actionbar get hide where action bar is toolbar but the some part of listview is hiding behind the tab. Here i have used AppBarLayout and toolbar having app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" and in my recylerview have  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" behaviour. I can use linear Layout but problem is for sliding of toolbar the AppBarLayout must be the child of CoordinatorLayout.

My activity having xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ameyo.genie.activity.HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>



        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
            app:theme="@style/Toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/action_bars"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
           />
            <ameyo.genie.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/home_fab_dial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dialpad_white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/pager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and my fragment having

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recentcall_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Am I doing something wrong in making the toolbar to slide on sliding the listview or there is another way of doing this without using any third library.

Comment: No need to use a third party library for tabs, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967941/whatsapp-like-collapsing-toolbar

Comment: Thanks for your response it help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
            app:theme="@style/Toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/action_bars"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
           />
            <ameyo.genie.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                />
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

When you put your component, order them by the position, every component will be over the precedent, if there's no space !

Comment: After doing this the tab get hide and on scrolling of listview the tab get show on toolbar or actionbar

Comment: try to invert the order of SlidingTabLayout and Toolbar

Comment: By doing this the toolbar get hide and only tabs are there on action bar\

Comment: Sorry i have'nt seen that you put framelayout inside the AppBarLayout . Now it is not hiding and its working properly but now the problem is that  list does not get scroll.

Comment: add a scroll layout, or check if you desactivate the scrolling in your list.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i have solved my issue which i have updated above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel Nugent that I forgot to write  `android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs`" inside viewpager and also remove framelayout and height must be wrapcontent now my final code is this which is working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ameyo.genie.activity.HomeActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="6dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/action_bars"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
            app:theme="@style/Toolbar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            />

        <ameyo.genie.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/home_fab_dial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dialpad_white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/pager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```