# Text inside tabs of a TabLayout is not centered

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using a TabLayout. I want full screen width to be filled by TabLayout, so I added `app:tabGravity="fill"`. My problem is that now tab text is not centered. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Please see pink bar under Tab one]

The code of TabLayout is as follows:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#ff00ff"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />
```

I have seen many questions but none of them solves my problem. Any help is highly appreciated. For details I want to tell that I am trying [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35968394/5969624). Device is running on Android 2.3.6 (API 10). Screen is 320x240.

Comment: Use this for adjusting the text: android:gravity="center" OR android:textAlignment="center"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for adjusting the text:

```
android:gravity="center" OR android:textAlignment="center"
```

you should create a custom tab .. you are using these attributes for tabLayout which will not work ... the example link you provided above uses a file named custom_tab.xml . Use that for defining your textView and put these attributes inside it.

Comment: None of `android:gravity="center"` and `android:textAlignment="center"` is able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

just do like this:-

```
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
       app:tabGravity="fill"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to xml layout `android:gravity="center"`

you can refer this for more details

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Comment: Already tried. It's not working. I have seen other questions which tell to use `android:gravity="center"`.

Comment: are you using textview for displaying .

Comment: you should add gravity in text view not in tab layout.

Comment: I have already told that I am following answer to some question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35968394/5969624

Comment: you have missed it tab layout there does noot have tab gravity.

Answer (score 0):

In default the text should be center if you do not overrided with another not centered style.

any way if you sure `Gravity="center"` is not working, you can also put your custom layout as tab background. so you create a relative layout that has a `textView` in center of it. ( in this way you are free to put wanted layout as tab items) so feel free.

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.getTabAt(postion).setCustomView(resourceId);
```

hope helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, the preview in Android Studio shows the tab labels centered, but on the device they are left-aligned.

As other answer have suggested, using a custom view is a good way to gain control over the layout.

Create a layout file `layout/view_tab_label.xml` with a `TextView` with id `@android:id/text1`, so you can still specify the tab text inside the `TabItem`:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/tab_label"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Reference this layout from the tab item (`android:layout` attribute in each `TabItem`):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/selected_tab"
    app:tabBackground="@color/tab_background">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout="@layout/view_tab_label"
        android:text="@string/tab_1_title" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout="@layout/view_tab_label"
        android:text="@string/tab_2_title" />

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Create a color resource file `color/tab_label.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/selected_tab" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/unselected_tab" android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that TextView wasn't centered inside layout. Not Text itself

So. In TextView.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```