# Add fixed tab bar pinned to top with scrolled content?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, tabs

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35968394/8244559) answer, but I could not achieve the same look & behavior as my current main activity.

What changes should I make to my existing main activity to add a fixed tab bar pinned to top with scrolled content like in the image below?

[image]

Here's a .GIF of my current main activity: i.stack.imgur.com/Yj0cv.gif

Here's a link to the **full** project called `android`: https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/tree/master/android

Here's `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@drawable/button_selector</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@drawable/button_selector</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/FriendlyButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FriendlyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTitle</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

Here's `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addMessageImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEND"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The link you provided seems to be a complete answer for what it looks like you are trying to do.  Could you tell us why that answer does not work for you?  Is it just the parts of your layout they are not using (ProgressBar, MyOwnView, etc.)?

Comment: @Gary99 It doesn't look the same. Everything's out of place, out of order etc.

Comment: @Gary99 I edited my question with more information!

Answer (score 4):

Put your fixed view's in `RelativeLayout` and move scrolling content inside `CoordinatorLayout`. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
                </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/adView" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addMessageImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="SEND" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Google has Design support library and with it you can implement Collapsing Toolbar and you do not need any 3rd party libraries!!

> In addition to pinning a view, you can use  app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" (and optionally app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" to set the parallax multiplier) to implement parallax scrolling (say of a sibling ImageView within the CollapsingToolbarLayout)

And as example you can use this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="186dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

And do not forget to add `compile "com.android.support:design:25.3.1"` in your module  `build.gradle`

**UPDATE 1:**
First of all, you need to create a `CoordinatorLayout`.

> All the new components use a new concept called Behavior that is used by the Coordinator Layout to take some actions based on different interactions.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can use `fitsSystemWindows` on any item you want to be painted below the status bar.

Then you need to add an `AppBarLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And then inside that, you can add something like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, please give a full working answer implementing my question's code :) It's a bit confusing like this.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. I'd like to point out that I need a custom solution for my project. I will update the question with a link to the full project in a few moments. The activity to modify is called `MainActivity`.

Comment: I will immediately award the bounty and accept the answer that solves my problem.

Comment: @JonathanDoe Correct me if I'm wrong but you want to have a `recyclerView` in the middle, an `Edittext` and a send `button` on bottom.
And what for top ?

Answer (score 3):

Just created behavior, what you want. Shouldn't be so complicated. So here is main XML for all Views. But I also have already created project for this sample, please write here, if I need to share full project.

**SCREENS**

[image]

**MAIN XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**TO YOUR EXAMPLE**

I share here another example, which should suite your code. I attached all view Ids for your examples. Check it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom |center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/addMessageImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="SEND" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'd like to point out that I need a custom solution for my project. I will update the question with a link to the full project in a few moments. The activity to modify on is called `MainActivity`.

Comment: @JonathanDoe Cannot understand issue. So you just used this example, but it doesn't work for you?

Comment: @JonathanDoe You should use this my example above, to get expected result. You cannot done it, with simple Views.

Comment: I mean what modifications should I do to my **existing** project (link in the question) to add a fixed tab bar to my main activity? Do you understand? :)

Comment: I will immediately award the bounty and accept the answer that solves my problem.

Comment: Thanks. But, the `EditText` and the `Send` button aren't behaving correctly. Look: http://i.imgur.com/ayZ7sKc.gif

Comment: `EditText` and `SEND` should be like this instead: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj0cv.gif

Comment: @JonathanDoe I suppose it's enough, for this example. Just configure bottom layout as you want.

Comment: I tried but I'm unable to do that with your `FrameLayout`. As I said, I'll immediately award the +100 bounty when the problem us solved.

Answer (score 1):

try above code

Style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@drawable/button_selector</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@drawable/button_selector</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/FriendlyButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="FriendlyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTitle</item>

</style>
```

here if you don't want to change property to 'NoActionBar' then alternatively set it in AndroidManifest.xml file like above

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"/>
```

activity_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <include
            layout="@layout/maincontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adView"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/addMessageImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="SEND"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

maincontent.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```